# Jquery getJSON throws: "Failed to load resource: cancelled" in Safari

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, safari

I've found a few posts (here and across the web) on this issue and tried the proposed solutions with no success, but there were some differences in the original issue.  My example seems very straightforward, so I'd love to get some input on this.  Here's the code:

```
theURI = "https://<?= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>/validate.php";
theData = {
    'validationType' : 'login',
    'ident' : document.getElementById("login_ident").value,
    'password' : document.getElementById("login_pw").value,
    'loginTries' : <?= $loginTries ?>
}
$.getJSON(theURI, theData, function() {alert('Success!')});
```

The "Success!" alert shows up fine but the error "**Failed to load resource:  cancelled**" flashes through the error console.  "validate.php" is as follows (some of the server code has been omitted for clarity), assume the variables are all basically valid values:

```
<?php
echo '{';
echo '"result" : "' . $login_success . '",';
echo '"loginTries" : "' . $loginTries . '",';
echo '"feedback" : "' . $loginFeedback . '",';
echo '"feedbackClass" : "' . $loginTextClass . '",';
if($login_success) {
    echo '"userData" : {';
    $firstPass=true;
    foreach ($g_aUserData as $theKey => $theValue) {
        if(!$firstPass) echo ","; else $firstPass=false;
        echo '"' . $theKey . '" : "' . $theValue . '"';
    }
    echo '}';
}
echo '}';
?>
```

Which generates (sample data, of course):

```
{"result" : "1","loginTries" : "0","feedback" : "SUCCESSFUL LOGIN!","feedbackClass" : "login_text","userData" : {"firstName" : "Gomez","memberID" : "39203","lastName" : "Aadams","lastLogin" : "","message" : "","credHash" : "3baf7a67271ecfd93kdsid33s2a65c16a9413f652"}}
```

Which reformats to:

```
{
    "result" : "1",
    "loginTries" : "0",
    "feedback" : "SUCCESSFUL LOGIN!",
    "feedbackClass" : "login_text",
    "userData" : {
        "firstName" : "Gomez",
        "memberID" : "39203",
        "lastName" : "Aadams",
        "lastLogin" : "",
        "message" : "",
        "credHash" : "3baf7a67271ecfd93kdsid33s2a65c16a9413f652"
    }
}
```

Any ideas?  I've tried:

1) Loading the data into a querystring and omitting the data param entirely.
2) Changing the call to be relative.
3) Changing the "https" to "http".

**UPDATE**: OK.  Based on comments, I paid my stupid tax and had the code generate the JSON data without any HTML trimmings.  Strangely, I still am getting the *same* error.  Tried the same fixes noted above, still not working.

Comment: Why are you putting your JSON inside an HTML page?

Comment: Should I just have it raw output?  Gah.  I hope it's not that simple. (well, I do but I'll be embarassed).  Going off to try generating it raw, now.

Comment: OK.  Made the update to the code (and the question.)  I also verified the generated JSON code with JSLint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it turns out that the problem had naught to do with the ajax call, but with the form (that had been converted to Ajax) that was being used for the inputs.  Once I added "return false" to the form, everything cleared up.

But I must say thanks to lonesomeday for reminding me just how AJAX works (it'd been awhile since I've coded.)  Over the course of prepping the question initially, I was able to dig out some other errors before the post, so all-in-all, simply asking the question helped immensely.